# Printing char value using reference

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, reference

I'm having trouble trying to `printf()` a `char` variable.

I declare two arrays, one for the brand names and the other for the values, based on which value is the biggest I get the appropriate brand name based on the position in the array.

Well, printing `marca` here works perfectly. But when I try to print it outside the function it doesn't.

Any idea?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void fabricanteDeModa(char *);

int main()
{
    char marca;
    fabricanteDeModa(&marca);
    printf("%s", marca); //Not working (already tried changing to %c)

    return 0;
}

void fabricanteDeModa(char *marca)
{
    int apple = 5;
    int xiaomi = 10;
    int samsung = 7;
    int htc = 12;
    int lg = 15;
    int zte = 10;
    int nokia = 2;

    char marcas[7][10] = {
        "apple",
        "xiaomi",
        "samsung",
        "htc",
        "lg",
        "zte",
        "nokia"
    };

    int valores[7] = { apple, xiaomi, samsung, htc, lg, zte, nokia };
    int i;
    int maxVal = valores[0];
    int pos = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        if (valores[i] > maxVal)
        {
            maxVal = valores[i];
            // Find the index of the max value
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    marca = marcas[pos];
    printf("%s\n", marca); //This Works
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just make your function return `char*`. Or you need to pass a `char**` and then dereference it.

Comment: Look at the compiler warnings. In the first snippet `char marca;` isn't the string that `%s` is expecting.

Comment: It's some work from the university it's supposed to be that way and I cant change the function's prototype. Could you explain in more depth what do you mean with char**? Thanks.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging service. You should narrow down the problem in your program and present only a very small program that illustrates the specific problem you are unable to solve. Most often, narrowing down the problem actually reveals what the problem is and eliminates any need to post to Stack Overflow.

Comment: In the supposed MRE function `fabricanteDeModa` isn't even using `marca` argument.

Comment: Could you explain it further? @WeatherVane

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `char marca[/*somearraylength*/];` And it must be initialised before passing the `printf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Already tried, didn't work. Changing the code to
`
    char marca[50];
    fabricanteDeModa(&marca);
    printf("%s",marca);
`
Would give error and deleting the & work work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it looks like you want is the manufacturer brand with the largest value returned to your string and then printed.  In order for me to get that to work, here are the bits I changed.

First, instead of defining a pointer to a character (which is fundamentally the same as a pointer to an "int") I defined a character array that was as large as the largest possible manufacturer name.  There are probably other ways to initialize the character array, but this is the simplest way I know.  I then pass the string name as the pointer reference to your function as noted in the following code snippet.

```
char marca[10];
fabricanteDeModa(marca);
```

In your current iteration of the "fabricantDeModa" function, you have the character arrary reference as your parameter, but as it currently stands, it was not getting updated within the function.  So, I added what I believe you were attempting to do which is store the manufacturer's name within that string.  To do that I added a "strcpy" command to place the manufacturer's name into your main level character array.

```
    }
    strcpy(marca, marcas[pos]);   /* Added this code */
    printf("Largest element = %d\n", pos);
    printf("La marca de moda es : %s\n", marcas[pos]); //This Works
}
```

Passing and updating strings (character arrays) can be tricky.  I hope this clarifies things for you.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

`marca` should be defined as a `char *` or better `const char *` and `fabricanteDeModa` should return the brand name, not take a pointer to `char` as posted.

To return the string, the array `marcas` should not be a 2D array of `char` with automatic storage (non-static local variable) whose elements will not be accessible after the function returns, you can instead use an array of string pointers.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *fabricanteDeModa(void);

int main() {
    const char *marca = fabricanteDeModa();
    printf("%s\n", marca);
    return 0;
}

const char *fabricanteDeModa(void) {
    int apple = 5;
    int xiaomi = 10;
    int samsung = 7;
    int htc = 12;
    int lg = 15;
    int zte = 10;
    int nokia = 2;

    const char *marcas[7] = { "apple", "xiaomi", "samsung", "htc", "lg", "zte", "nokia" };
    int valores[7] = { apple, xiaomi, samsung, htc, lg, zte, nokia };
    int i;
    int maxVal = valores[0];
    int pos = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < 7; ++i) {
        if (valores[i] > maxVal) {
            maxVal = valores[i];
            // Update the index of the max value
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    printf("Largest element = %d\n", pos);
    printf("La marca de moda es : %s\n", marcas[pos]); //This Works
    return marcas[pos];
}
```